# UITextField highlight text when user taps space

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` which i let user write tags as we do in stackoverflow. What i really want is exactly what stackoverflow does,with a slight difference which is to detect user's touch space button in keyboard.Well,stackoverflow searches instantaneously and display results.Instead i want user to tap space button. Do u guys have any idea,any tutorial that i can benefit from ? I'm sure i'm going to use UITextFieldDelegate method which is

`-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

But i don't know  how to highlight the words before user starts to tap another word .

Comment: You can detect the space character by implementing this UITextFieldDelegate method:

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string


Good luck with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get text highlighted u will have to use `NSAttributestring` and for that u will have use `UITextView` that supports `NSAttributestring`.

Refer [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView/) link that supports NSAttributestring

Do like this to detect space in `UITextField` like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     NSString *lastCharacter = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([string length]-1, 1)];
     if([lastCharacter isEqualToString:@" "])
     {
         //space button pressed
     }
     else
     { 
         // continue
     }
}
```